# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: false

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I've successfully run my flask app locally, but when I deploy it to my prod environment, I get this error:

```
[2019-08-26 00:15:36,229] ERROR in app: Exception on /formulas [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1244, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 552, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: false

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "app.py", line 96, in get_all_formulas
    for formula in query_results:
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3334, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3359, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 988, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1107, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1248, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1466, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
    File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 152, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1244, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 552, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: false
[SQL: SELECT all_formulas.id AS all_formulas_id, all_formulas.name AS all_formulas_name, all_formulas.abbreviation AS all_formulas_abbreviation, all_fo
rmulas.category_name AS all_formulas_category_name, all_formulas.category_id AS all_formulas_category_id, all_formulas.parent_id AS all_formulas_parent
_id, all_formulas.has_children AS all_formulas_has_children, all_formulas.function AS all_formulas_function 
FROM all_formulas 
WHERE all_formulas.parent_id IS NULL]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_api/app.py", line 96, in handle_user_exception
    app_handlers = self.error_handler_spec[None].get(None, ())
KeyError
```

As you can see, the main error is `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: false`.  However, `false` is nowhere in the SQL that SQLAlchemy generated.  I also tried this without SQLAlchemy and got the same result.

All my research seems to suggest that these errors are caused by some table or column in the query not existing.  However, my error is different because `false` is not a table, column, or even in the SQL.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

**Edit #1**

Here is the python SQLAlchemy model class:

```
class AllFormulas(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    abbreviation = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    category_name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    has_children = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=True)
    function = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)

    def as_dict(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'name': self.name,
            'abbreviation': self.abbreviation,
            'category': self.category_name,
            'parentId': self.parent_id,
            'hasChildren': self.has_children,
            'function': self.function
        }
```

Here is the python SQLAlchemy query call (see line after comment below):

```
@app.route('/formulas', methods=['GET', 'OPTIONS'])
    def get_all_formulas():
        if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
            return _build_cors_preflight_response()
        else:
            category = request.args.get('category')
            search = request.args.get('search')

            if category:
                query_results = AllFormulas.query.filter(AllFormulas.category_id == category)
            elif search:
                query_results = AllFormulas.query.filter(or_(AllFormulas.name.ilike('%{search}%'.format(search)),
                                                             AllFormulas.abbreviation.ilike('%{search}%'.format(search))))
            else:
                # This next line is being run and throws the SQLite error.
                query_results = AllFormulas.query.filter(AllFormulas.parent_id == None)

            json = []
            for formula in query_results:
                json.append(formula.as_dict())

            if IS_PROD:
                return json
            else:
                return _corsify_actual_response(json)
```

**Edit #2**

I queried on the SQLite database in my production environment directly using the sqlite3 command line.  Here is what I got:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-x-xx:~/apps/my-app/data$ sqlite3 math.db
SQLite version 3.11.0 2016-02-15 17:29:24
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> select *
   ...> from all_formulas;
Error: no such column: false
```

However, the same query works fine in my local environment:

```
sm7chrisjones:data chris.jones$ sqlite3 math.db
SQLite version 3.24.0 2018-06-04 14:10:15
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> select * from all_formulas;
0|Kilograms|kg|0|Medical|2|0|
0|Kilograms|kg|0|Medical|9|0|
0|Kilograms|kg|0|Medical|12|0|
0|Kilograms|kg|0|Medical|13|0|
0|Kilograms|kg|0|Medical|14|0|
0|Kilograms|kg|0|Medical|15|0|
1|Liters|l|0|Medical|2|0|
sqlite>
```

All that I do to deploy to prod is to upload the project to S3, log into my Ubuntu prod environment, and copy the project files from S3 to the prod environment.  Does anyone know why those steps would create this error?

Thank you!

Comment: did you check what you have in file with database sqlite3 ?

Comment: Please provide your Sqlalchemy constructed query (in python) and format of the table (output of “show create table all_formulas” for instance)

Comment: @bagerard - I've adde the SQLAlchemy python query above.  Does the SQLAlchemy python class suffice for the format of the table?

Comment: @furas - please see edit #2 above.  It seems it's a SQLite issue in prod only.  All I do to deploy is put the project in S3, log into my Ubuntu prod environment, and copy the files from S3 to the prod environment.  Do you know why those steps would cause this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @furas suggestion, I found that the tables in the app's SQLite database were returning query results correctly, but `all_formulas` (which is a view) was not.  Upon further investigation, it appears the `all_formulas` view SQL definition behaves differently between my local Mac environment and my Ubuntu prod environment.  The all_formulas view SQL definition is:

```
CREATE VIEW all_formulas as
select f.id,
       f.name, 
       f.abbreviation,
       c.id as category_id,
       c.name as category_name,
       fr.parent_id,
       case when (select count(*)
                  from formula_relationships
                  where parent_id = f.id) = 0
       then false -- THIS WAS CAUSING THE ERROR IN UBUNTU.
       else true
       end as has_children,
       f.function
from formula f
left join formula_relationships fr on f.id = fr.child_id
left join category c on f.category_id = c.id
where f.category_id = c.id;
```

I was able to fix the error by using the SQLite integers that represent `false` (0) and `true` (1).  So, the corrected view SQL definition is:

```
CREATE VIEW all_formulas as
select f.id,
       f.name, 
       f.abbreviation,
       c.id as category_id,
       c.name as category_name,
       fr.parent_id,
       case when (select count(*)
                  from formula_relationships
                  where parent_id = f.id) = 0
       then 0 --IS EQUIVALENT TO FALSE IN SQLITE
       else 1 --IS EQUIVALENT TO TRUE IN SQLITE
       end as has_children,
       f.function
from formula f
left join formula_relationships fr on f.id = fr.child_id
left join category c on f.category_id = c.id
where f.category_id = c.id;
```

Thank you all for your help in troubleshooting this!!